# Robin boundary condition for Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am considering the equation $\Delta u = 0 $ in $\Omega$ and $\alpha u + \frac{du}{dn} = g$ on the boundary.

My professor suggested to consider the program $\Delta v = 0$ in $\Omega$ and $\frac{dv}{dn} = g$, and let $L$ be the operator such that $Lg =v$. Then apply Fredholm theory to $L$.

I am confused how to get $u$ from the $v$ and $L$ that we constructed?

I see that after substitution, we have $u = L(g - \alpha u)$, but this is just equivalent to the original PDE. On the other hand, we know that the Neumann problem has a solution (by energy methods). But knowing $v$ doesn't seem to be helpful in getting $u$. Can you provide more details or a hint on how to proceed?